# Interaction of quantum particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, probability, interactions, quantum-measurements

I am still a student, so if the question is stupid, I apologize. If quantum particles interact with each other constantly and continuously (described by a single wave function in quantum mechanics or Feynman diagrams in quantum field theory), then why is the interaction between a quantum particle and a measuring device described probabilistically? After all, the interaction of two quantum particles is not a probabilistic process, they interact continuously, and not only from time to time. Probabilities arise only when it is necessary to measure the results of such an interaction.

Answer (score 1):

The probabilities have to do with the OUTCOME of the interaction. In general, an interaction can lead to plenty of results-each of which has a certain probability associated with it. That is, if the same interaction process was carried out, with similar external conditions, a large number of times, there'd be a different result each time, and the set of results can be described by a probability distribution. The  goal of our theory is to theoretically determine this distribution.

Comment: Keep in mind that the wave packets associated with two sub-atomic particles may overlap without interacting. In double slit interference, the incoming photon may (or may not) interact with a detector  electron near the maximum of the interference pattern, but will not interact with one at the minimum in the pattern.

Comment: @R.W.Bird There is always interaction, but sometimes it is so weak that it can be neglected.
This is exactly what the question is about. From the point of view of quantum mechanics, the photon interacts with all the electrons in the detector, but with different amplitudes. The modulus square determines which of these interactions will be detected by the macroscopic observer. After all, you cannot declare that the electron does not interact with anything before the detector.

Comment: @GRrocks Rather, not with the result of interaction, but with the result of observation.

Comment: When I speak of interaction, I'm assuming that all the energy of the photon is absorbed by a single electron.

Comment: @R.W. Bird So what? There is an amplitude that an electron will absorb a photon and an amplitude that will not absorb. The photon is in a superposition of two states (by the way, it is due to this superposition that the photon interferes with itself). That is, the interaction component always exists. In addition, the photon constantly interacts with the electron field, and this interaction is not probabilistic.